# Why does validation not fail on client side but fails on server side?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Right now, I have a form with several fields and on submit, I want to check if the username is taken or not. If taken, do nothing (show validation error), if not taken, successfully proceed onto the next form.

Here's what I have done so far:

View:

```
var RequestCreateAccount_Submit = function () {

        var res = false;
        ValidationAttribute.BlankValue(true);
        var form = $('form#RequestCreateAccount');
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
        var res = form.valid();
        var data = form.serialize();

        if (res) {
            $.ajax({
                url: Url.getFullUrl('Account/RequestCreateAccount_Submit'),
                type: 'Post',
                data: data,
                cache:false,
                success: function (data) {
                    //Next Dialog

                },
                error: AjaxLog.HandleAjaxCallFail
            });
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Controller:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RequestCreateAccount_Submit(UserAccount userAccount)      
    {
        //Check if username is unique
        if (!WebSecurity.UserExists(userAccount.UserName))
        {
            UserSession.AddValue(StateName.CreateOrEditAccount, "CurrentUserAccount", userAccount);
            JsonResult res = Json(new { Success = true, data = "", Message = "" });
            return res;
        }
        JsonResult jres = Json(new { Success = false, data = "", Message = "Username is already registered"});
        return jres;
    }
```

I tested it with a known username and it did hit the success=false (outside of the if statement) line and it did not go inside the if statment. So I know the validation on the server side works.

However, I am wondering why on the client side, it still success = true and the next dialog appeared. It did not fail on validation. What am I doing wrong on the client side?

Comment: What kind of validation are we talking about?

Comment: You haven't shown us what in your client code is supposed to make sure a user name isn't taken.  What does that code look like?

Comment: @Becuzz, I don't have client side validation for username. I mean to say, server side validation check works but in the client side code, the next dialog is still rendered.

Comment: Why are you not just using the built in `[Remote]` attribute and save your self writing all that (bad) script? `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);` is pointless. Assigning `var data = form.serialize();` before you check if the form is valid is just a waste

Comment: @StephenMuecke, for remote validation, what does my action have to return? Does it have to return jsonresult or can it return a bool? Thanks.

Comment: if successful, `return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` other wise `return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` to display the error message defined in the `RemoteAttribute` or `Json("some error message", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` to override the default mesage. See [How to: Implement Remote Validation in ASP.NET MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(VS.98).aspx)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I thought about avoiding Remote validation because I only want server side validation (due to sensitivity of username) but turns out, I still need to display qtip error if the username already exists and for that, I still need a custom attribute. So, I'm back here. Remote validation is pretty much client side validation right?

Comment: Yes its client side only. Personally I always refactor the code to a (say) `private bool IsUnique(string userName)` method that I call  from the Remote attributes method (for client side valiation), and again in the POST method (to protect against a malicious user)

Comment: Actually, just noticed your posting back the whole model (because you appear to be wanting to add it to session) but `[Remote]` would not allow you to do that. Although in any case I don't see the need to do that from an ajax call - wouldn't you only need to add the model to session in the POST method if the model is valid?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, hmm actually. I would like to pick your brain on how to best approach this scenario with remote. I want to check username on form submission. That means, if I have a separate action for UserNameExists() and RequestCreateAccount_Submit(). For Remote, I would use UserNameExists that returns a jsonresult but how do I check that on submission? That is, do I need two ajax calls... one for UserNameExists() and one for RequestCreateAccount_Submit() or...?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81586/discussion-between-kala-j-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that your controller does actually successfully return a result. It is just that the successful result indicates an error. While logically similar at this point, they are very different. Error is going to be reserved for actual exceptions thrown or 404 no route present type of scenarios.

You should check for the response status inside of your success callback function

***[`dotNetFiddle Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1h4V1R)***

```
$.ajax({
  url: Url.getFullUrl('Account/RequestCreateAccount_Submit'),
  type: 'Post',
  data: data,
  cache:false,
  success: function (data) {
     if(data.Success === false){
         AjaxLog.HandleAjaxCallFail();
         // this may not make as much sense though
         // as the request didn't actually fail, just the action did
         //TODO: code for name fail
         return;//do not process next dialog
     }
     //Next Dialog

  },
  error: AjaxLog.HandleAjaxCallFail
  });
```

Comment: hmm okay, I will give it a try but I am curious about one thing: Is checking if my form data is valid on the client side interfering with the server side validation check for the username? No right? Is the way I have it set up above alright? Thanks.

Comment: No that will not affect server side. It just parses the form's elements which have the validation data types properly set and looks to see if they are valid according to the validation requirements on each element. It then serializes them for submission so that the model binder will be able to accept the data. None of that will affect your server side check.

Comment: It still went to the next dialog :O I followed your approach: if(data.success == "False") { return;} //next

Comment: Opps, I mean I did return Success with Cap S.

Comment: @KalaJ - Hm, perhaps .Success does not equal "False" and has been implicitly converted. In which case you could compare it with `false` as opposed to the string value.

Comment: I noticed something interestingin debugging, when I return jres with Success= false, the AJAX if statement never gets hit. Why is that?

Comment: @KalaJ - What do you mean "never gets hit"? It should evaluate if the success callback function is executed.

Comment: I will try to replicate on the dotNetFiddle but It still goes to next dialog. I'm not sure why? I'm using firebug and it's buggy as heck, so I'm not if it's a firebug issue or not but it's not going inside  success: function(data) {} but then if not, why would it show the next dialog? hmm

Comment: makes me sad :( I'm not sure why it's going to the next dialog @_@

Comment: And you cannot reproduce it in the dotNetFiddle? If you use `console.log(data)` and look inside of the firefox console what does the response data look like? Also, you should be using chrome :P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81578/discussion-between-kala-j-and-travis-j).

Answer (score 1):

The `success = false` of your result object doesn't means that the request failed. It stands only for `data.success`, nothing more. The resquest is still *successful*(HTTP 200), which I think is the right response code. If you return an error code like `new HttpStatusCodeResult(404, "error message");` it means that your request failed, but it isn't true.

You request works whatever the result of the check is. So you may check this in your `success` callback, instead of the `error` callback:

```
success: function(data) {
    if (data.success) {
        //Next Dialog
    }
    else {
        // error message
    }
}
```

Comment: This wont work as written. Keep in mind that when the server returns a boolean value it is converted to string form. So boolean true in c# is actually "True" in the response, and false is "False". if("False") in JavaScript is true.

Comment: @TravisJ I know, it was an example only, otherwise I would paste all the code like you did. Maybe if `dataType: "json"` was defined, it could work.

Comment: @TravisJ [**dataType**: *"json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object*](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)

Comment: Ah right, it has an auto converter. Yes, if you used that it would convert false to false. Although you would still want to make sure you use an existing property `.Success` and not `.success` which is not present.